# How to add third-party scripts in Angular 6 custom elements

Tags: angular6, custom-element

For custom elements in Angular 6, how do I add scripts like popper.js and jquery as they are not functional when added to the “angular.json” file? Importing bootstrap in the css component works perfectly.

Comment: Did you try to add them?

Comment: Or maybe put them as dependencies in index.html with scripg tag

Comment: I added them to the index.html. It only works/responds once, then it is no longer responsive.

Answer (score 0):

1) Usage

```
npm i -g popper
```

2) Add path under the 'build' inside 'angular.json'

```
"scripts": [
             "node_modules/popper/popper.js"
           ]
```

Please verify the file inside the node_modules.

Comment: This only works when I’m not creating custom elements in Angular 6.